# Which clustering/partitioning algorithms can operate on arbitrary pairwise similarity or distance matrices?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I'm relatively new to cluster analysis, and I'm exploring options for general-purpose, non-hierarchical, strict partitioning of data based on a pre-computed $N\times N$ pairwise similarity matrix.  The matrix must be computable from an arbitrary user-specified (i.e., non-canned) similarity metric.

Which established methods satisfy the above criteria?

I've read up a bit on the clustering algorithms [included in Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html), but I've failed to spot any so far that exactly match my description, though I might be overlooking something.

Comment: Because there are none, the choice of dis/similarity metric is critical, you are better off using a canned metric, determined based on the context.

Comment: I don't quite get your question... on the title you ask for an algorithm, which might easily be KNN, but on the body you ask for a similarity measure, which might be $1/(1+||a-b||)$ for what I can see

Comment: @user2974951  The similarity metric is specific to the problem, and none of the canned metrics I could find is an adequate substitute.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia  I didn't try to include all of the relevant information in the title, as it would have been too long.   As far as I can tell, a similarity metric can be computed from any valid distance metric -- e.g., similarity = 1/(1+distance) , so unless I'm missing something, they can be used interchangeably.